# RAILS : Performing calculations on fields in the model.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the [event_calendar gem](https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar) in a rails app. Event_calendar adds the following to the event model to define start and end dates for the calendar view.

```
has_event_calendar :start_at_field  => 'sdate', :end_at_field => 'tdate'
```

where `sdate` and `tdate` are fields in the model.

However, in my case I am not storing end dates in the database. End dates are calculated based on a duration field, i.e. sdate + duration. I've had no problem calculating end dates elsewhere, but can't seem to set it up for event_calendar.

Basically, I need to do

```
has_event_calendar :start_at_field  => 'sdate', :end_at_field => '[event.sdate]+[event.duration]'
```

but have been unable to figure out the correct syntax.

1. Is it possible/advisable to perform calculations like this in the model? If so, what is the correct syntax for grabbing and manipulating database values?
2. Should I move this calculation into a variable? What are the pros and cons of doing this?

I've been struggling with this for a while. Grateful for a helping hand to learn how this works.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

The model in question looks like this:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110607040735
#
# Table name: schedules
#
#  id                 :integer         not null, primary key
#  sdate              :date
#  tdate              :date
#  duration           :integer
#  created_at         :datetime
#  updated_at         :datetime
#

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :sdate, :tdate, :duration

  has_event_calendar :start_at_field  => 'sdate', :end_at_field => calculated_tdate

  scope :default, :order => 'schedules.sdate ASC'

  def calculated_tdate
       self.sdate+self.cruise.duration
  end

end
```

but this is generating an error

```
undefined local variable or method `calculated_tdate' for #<Class:0x10b62cb98>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having discussed this with issue with event_calendar's developers, it seems that it is not possible to use a calculated end date at this time. The plugin relies on having an end date column specified in the underlying table. I'm sure the plugin can be hacked to provide the required behavior. I'll add more if I make any progress with this. Thanks to all who gave suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the gem is working. If its really querying the database you would need to store theses data in the database but if its only calling the given method in acceptence that the attribute is an ActiveRecord generated method you could manually define the method like this in your model:

```
def tdate
     self.sdate+self.duration
end
```

Give it a try...

About your secound question: Its a database design principle to not store data in the database that could be calculated from other fields that are already in the database as long as there is no other alternative!

Comment: thanks @davidb. I've added `def calculated_tdate self.sdate+self.duration end` to the model. With `has_event_calendar .... :end_at_field => 'calculated_tdate'` I get `PGError: ERROR:  column "calculated_tdate" does not exist`. So, in this case the gem is querying the database. If I alter the syntax and remove quotes `:end_at_field => calculated_tdate` I get `undefined local variable or method 'calculated_tdate' for #<Class:0x102a4b110>`. I've already defined the variable with `def calculated_tdate`, so I dont understand this. Have I overlooked something, or is this just not possible?

Comment: why do you write `  has_event_calendar :start_at_field  => 'sdate', :end_at_field => calculated_tdate` instead of `has_event_calendar :start_at_field  => 'sdate', :end_at_field => 'calculated_tdate'`?

Comment: I've tried both. If `calculated_tdate` is contained in quotes, then it generates a database error `PGError: ERROR: column "calculated_tdate" does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call

```
object.calculate_tdate
```

to get the end date

Comment: thanks @deathhammer. This looks interesting, but I don't understand how to use it. Where can I call this, and how do I define it? Excuse my ignorance, but this has got me stumped!